# Disable retry/run again option for pipeline job

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I need to disable the retry/run again option for a job in Gitlab CI/CD?
[Retry button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phCkl.png)

I thought setting retry to 0 for that particular job would do the job but it does not.

The other option I thought might work would be to delete or remove the job from the pipeline once it has completed successfully but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1):

The job needs to be archived to no longer be retried.

On [GitLab.com](https://gitlab.com), jobs are archived after `30 days`. In self-hosted, they are never archived.
To change the value in self-hosted, the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/continuous_integration.html#archive-jobs) explains how to change it, but it can not be less than `1 day`.

---

*The documentation on how to:*

### Archive jobs

Archiving jobs is useful for reducing the CI/CD footprint on the system by removing some of the capabilities of the jobs (metadata stored in the database needed to run the job), but persisting the traces and artifacts for auditing purposes.
To set the duration for which the jobs are considered as old and expired:

1. On the top bar, select **Main menu > Admin**.
2. On the left sidebar, select **Settings > CI/CD**.
3. Expand the **Continuous Integration and Deployment** section.
4. Set the value of **Archive jobs**.
5. Select **Save changes** for the changes to take effect.

After that time passes, the jobs are archived in the background and no longer able to be retried. Make it empty to never expire jobs. It has to be no less than `1 day`, for example: `15 days`, `1 month`, `2 years`.

For the value set for [GitLab.com](https://gitlab.com), see Scheduled job archiving.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to make it so that the job is unable to be retried straight after it passes? within seconds.